# What is wrong with this way of loading C++ QStringList as a model for a QML ListView?

Tags: qt, qml

This program fails silently, no message appears in the debug mode or in the release mode, the window does not show, you can see the program.exe running in the task manager though. What is going on ? how to fix it ? why it does fail ? why there is no message appear ?

The QML interface file

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.5

ListView {
    width: 100; height: 100

    model: myModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 25
        width: 100
        Text { text: modelData }
    }
}
```

The c++ main file

```
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStringList dataList;
    dataList.append("item 1");
    dataList.append("item 2");
    dataList.append("item 3");
    dataList.append("item 4");
    dataList.append("item 5");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel",QVariant::fromValue(dataList) );

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not create a window, neither in C++ nor in QML.

There are two ways to create a window with QtQuick:

1. Instead of using `QQmlApplicationEngine`, use the C++ class `QQuickView`, which inherits from `QQuickWindow`. Remember to call `show()`. This is what the example at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-stringlistmodel-example.html does.
2. If you use `QQmlApplicationEngine`, you need to have a [Window](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) somewhere in your QML file. Remember to set `visible` to true. `QQmlApplicationEngine` does not inherit from any window base class, that's why the window needs to be created in QML.

Comment: This makes me look like a fool, thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Why the window is not visible by default ?

Comment: I want to be able to design model classes that work with QML views. Can I make them and test them under console application ? is there a ready made console class that is specifically made to test modelClasses ?

Comment: I don't know why windows are not visible by default, actually I'm not sure that's the case, I just think I remember it.

Comment: There is https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test that tests your model for errors. If you mean to print the model content on the console, I'm not aware of anything like that. KDAB's Gammary tool (https://www.kdab.com/gammaray/) can show the content of models in a UI for debugging.